# DevTools HtmlやCssのチェックのアドオン

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

DevToolsのデフォルトにはJavascriptのチェックツールは装備されていますが、HtmlやCssはChromeのアドオンにあるみたいですが、お勧めのものがあれば教えてください。

尚、ググれば探すことができますが、実際に使っている方からの回答をお待ちします。

Comment: このサイトでは扱いずらい質問のようです。「お勧めは何ですか？」やいわゆるアンケートはこのサイトでは扱うことができません。[どのような質問は避けるべきですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)を参考に質問を組み立てなおしてみてください。

Comment: 例えば「Aのツールはこういうことでは利用できなくて困っています。代わりとなるようなものはありますか」とかだったら、質問としては問題ないです。

Comment: "使っている人の評価" という意味では Chrome ウェブストアにも載っているはずなので、それらも参考にできるはずです。欲しい機能などもう少し具体的に絞り込まないと、keitaro_so さんが指摘の通りアンケート質問になってしまいます。